# Resolve PostFailedForSomeDocumentsException exception during indexing

Tags: content-search, azure-search

During (manually triggered) indexing of the master database, I get the following exception (stack trace below). Using Sitecore 8.2u7 with SXA 1.7.

```
27608 10:43:03 ERROR [Index=sitecore_master_index] Commit failed
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch batch)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.Commit()

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.PostFailedForSomeDocumentsException
Message: Partial success for insert or update. Some documents succeeded, but at least one failed.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.PostDocuments(String jsonString)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch batch)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<PostDocuments>b__0(ISearchService searchService)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
Message: {"@odata.context":"https://wonkey-donkey.search.windows.net/indexes('sitecore-master-index')/$metadata#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01.IndexResult)","value":[{"key":"3cd50abca6dae4d4fe8174aeedddd81a","status":true,"errorMessage":null,"statusCode":201},
```

I've truncated the exception response from Azure for brevity, but the failing response of interest is

```
{
     "key":"aeaa7458b10a04593a6ef20bbbbc12f1",
     "status":false,
     "errorMessage":"Field 'content_1' contains a term that is too large to process. The max length for UTF-8 encoded terms is 32766 bytes. The most likely cause of this error is that filtering, sorting, and/or faceting are enabled on this field, which causes the entire field value to be indexed as a single term. Please avoid the use of these options for large fields.",
     "statusCode":400
},
```

I've tried searching that "key" value in Sitecore and it does not correspond to a template ID, so I assume this must be an ID for the field in Azure or a unique ID for the request/batch. Can anyone confirm what this is and whether I can use it to diagnose what is going on?

The field name "content_1" suggests to me that this is one of a number of duplicate field names and so the indexing code appends the number to make them unique. I don't have a "content 1" or "content_1" field anywhere in my solution. I have tried excluding from indexing all fields called "content", but I still get the same problem. I really don't know where this field is coming from as all fields named content have been excluded. I have also queried all items where a "content" field is not null or empty and have tried excluding the templates of the found items, but that does not resolve the error either. I am making a patch for `defaultCloudIndexConfiguration` which the other indexes reference via `<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration">`.

Comment: I love the Wonkey Donkey reference 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `content_1` is not a template field. It is a computed field for indexing media items such as Word or PDF documents. My attempt to exclude fields named "content" was pointless!

I tried to `patch:delete` this computed field, but that caused another error:

> Field 'content___s' contains a term that is too large to process. The max length for UTF-8 encoded terms is 32766 bytes. The most likely cause of this error is that filtering, sorting, and/or faceting are enabled on this field, which causes the entire field value to be indexed as a single term. Please avoid the use of these options for large fields.

My colleague [Miguel](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/3878/miguel-minoldo) pointed me to this Sitecore support ticket which should resolve the issue https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.218625 (download [here](https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.218625/releases)).

What we also found to work (although may affect search functionality in some way) is to add a patch file as below:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultCloudIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure">
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.FieldMaps.CloudFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="_content">
                <patch:attribute name="facetable">NO</patch:attribute>
                <patch:attribute name="filterable">NO</patch:attribute>
                <patch:attribute name="sortable">NO</patch:attribute>
              </field>
              <field fieldName="text">
                <patch:attribute name="facetable">NO</patch:attribute>
                <patch:attribute name="filterable">NO</patch:attribute>
                <patch:attribute name="sortable">NO</patch:attribute>
              </field>
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
        </defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```